# Scrapyd 404 to get "curl http://localhost:6800/listjobs.json?project=myproject":No such Resource

Tags: python-3.x, scrapyd

listjobs.json?project=myproject is 404

but others can get,for example:listspiders.json?project=myproject...

```sh
curl http://localhost:6800/listjobs.json?project=myproject
```

Comment: Scrapyd version is 1.2.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forget to write the configure:

```sh
[services]
schedule.json     = scrapyd.webservice.Schedule
cancel.json       = scrapyd.webservice.Cancel
addversion.json   = scrapyd.webservice.AddVersion
listprojects.json = scrapyd.webservice.ListProjects
listversions.json = scrapyd.webservice.ListVersions
listspiders.json  = scrapyd.webservice.ListSpiders
delproject.json   = scrapyd.webservice.DeleteProject
delversion.json   = scrapyd.webservice.DeleteVersion
listjobs.json     = scrapyd.webservice.ListJobs
daemonstatus.json = scrapyd.webservice.DaemonStatus
```